# Android : How to put right to left animation for viewpager

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

Please have look at below code,

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==1){

                    Log.d("MAIN_ACTIVITY", "POSITION " + position);

                    viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
                        @Override
                        public void transformPage(View page, float position) {

                            Animation logoMoveAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.logoanimation);
                            page.startAnimation(logoMoveAnimation);

                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, null);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
});
```

**logoanimation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale android:fromXScale="0.0" android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:duration="700" android:fillBefore="false" />
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-200" android:fromYDelta="-200"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

Current animation is fade in fade out . But I want to put right to left animation whether elements of the viewpager move forward or backward .

Have any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: are you using tabs with fragments along with adapter ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan : I am not using tabs but I use fragments with the viewpager.

Comment: kindly post the code that you use to switch fragments in the view pager